# include content file inside PCL within Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have a Xamarin.iOS app.  It links to a C# PCL.  Within the PCL, I have a text file Foo.txt.  Its build action is set to Content and Copy Always.  Yet when running on the iOS simulator from Visual Studio, I usually can't find it anywhere in the app bundle.

One time I actually did find it, at:

```
PortableLibrary/Foo.txt.
```

But other times it has not appeared.  What could be the matter?

Comment: `EmbeddedResource` should work. you then extract the resource from the assembly at runtime

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just tested it on the latest Xamarin.IOS version and it works just fine. Make sure that you rebuilt after changing the file settings. But its not found within the .app file if thats what you mean.